# Block content renders in wrong place

Tags: pug

I'm having a problem getting the content of a Pug block to render in the correct spot.

I've tried changing the name of the Block, append/prepend.

```
// Standard.pug
block content
    header
        block header
```

```
// _Header.pug
.col-lg
    block headerTop
.col-lg
    block right
```

```
// Index.pug
block header
    include ../components/Common/_Header.pug
        block headerTop
            include ../components/Identity/_Logo.pug
        block right
            nav.mega-menu
```

I'd expect the  to end up nested under the first .col-lg, but the compiled HTML looks like:

```
<header>
    <div class="col-lg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg">
        <a class="logo" href="/" title="Logo">
            <img src="/assets/img/logos/logo-stacked.svg" alt="Logo">
        </a>
        <nav class="mega-menu"></nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

I'm only moderately comfortable with Pug, so I'm sure it's some basic rule I'm unaware of, but I haven't been able to find anyone else having the same problem. I'd appreciated any help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the [relevant page](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html) in the pug docs?

Comment: I have, but I haven't been able to find anything wrong with what I'm doing. Any recommendations?

Comment: Indentation is very important in pug.  I'd suggest you read the docs again and compare their examples to what you have.

Comment: Hi @Graham, I've read it over again and I'm not seeing an example that really lines up with what I'm trying to achieve or a reason that the `a.logo` is winding up in the second `.col-lg`. I've tried adjusting the indentation in every way I can come up with. The only way I've been able to get it to work is to move the `include ... _Header.pug` back to the Standard.pug file.